# Sum up the values based on conditions coming form list and dict

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, aggregate

I have min 12 periods in list, these are not fixed might have more based on the selected product.
Also, I have a dict which has period as key and products as list of values.

```py
{
    "20191": ["prod1","prod2","prod3"],
    "20192": ["prod2","prod3"],
    "20193": ["prod2"]
}
```

II need to select the data based on period and compute the sum of the respective period, amount.

sample_data

| period | product | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20191 | prod1 | 30 |
| 20192 | prod1 | 30 |
| 20191 | prod2 | 20 |
| 20191 | prod3 | 60 |
| 20193 | prod1 | 30 |
| 20193 | prod2 | 30 |

output

| period | product | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20191 | prod1 | 110 |
| 20192 |  | 0 |
| 20193 | prod3 | 30 |

Basically, for each of the period, select only those products from the dict, and sum it up.

My code which is taking lot of time:

```
list_series = []
df = spark.read.csv(path,header=True)
periods = df.select("period").distinct().collect()
for period in periods:
  df1 = df.filter(f"period = {period}").filter(F.col("product").isin(dict["period"]).groupBy("priod","product").agg(F.sum("Amount").alias("Amount")
  list_series.append(df1)
dataframe = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll,list_series)
```

Is there any way, I can modify and increase the performance?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Flatten the input dictionary into list of tuples then create a new spark dataframe called `filters`, then `join` this dataframe with the original one by columns `periods` and `product`, then groupby `period` and aggregate `amount` using `sum`

```
d = [(i, k) for k, v in dct.items() for i in v]
filters = spark.createDataFrame(d, schema=['product', 'period'])

(
    df
    .join(filters, on=['period', 'product'], how='right')
    .groupby('period')
    .agg(F.sum('amount').alias('amount'))
    .fillna(0)
)
```

##### Result

```
+------+------+
|period|amount|
+------+------+
| 20191|   110|
| 20192|     0|
| 20193|    30|
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following input:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('20191', 'prod1', 30),
     ('20192', 'prod1', 30),
     ('20191', 'prod2', 20),
     ('20191', 'prod3', 60),
     ('20193', 'prod1', 30),
     ('20193', 'prod2', 30)],
    ['period', 'product', 'amount'])

periods = ["20191", "20192", "20193"]
period_products = {
    "20191": ["prod1","prod2","prod3"],
    "20192": ["prod2","prod3"],
    "20193": ["prod2"]
}
```

To make your script more performant, you will need to remove steps which create several dfs FROM ONE and then union them all back together. Do it in one dataframe without splitting.

You can create the filter condition in Python (a filter before the join should add performance boost), supply it  to the filter function and then aggregate.

```py
conds = [f"((period = '{p}') and (product ='{prod}'))" for p in periods for prod in period_products[p]]
cond = ' or '.join(conds)

df_periods = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(p, i) for p in periods for i in period_products[p]],
    ['period', 'product']
)

df = (df_periods
    .join(df.filter(cond), ['period', 'product'], 'left')
    .groupBy('period', 'product')
    .agg(F.sum('amount').alias('amount'))
)

df.show()
# +------+-------+------+
# |period|product|amount|
# +------+-------+------+
# | 20191|  prod2|    20|
# | 20191|  prod1|    30|
# | 20191|  prod3|    60|
# | 20193|  prod2|    30|
# | 20192|  prod2|  null|
# | 20192|  prod3|  null|
# +------+-------+------+
```

Comment: It is working fine for less data but if there are more than 15periods and for each period if there are 8000 products it is not working, mainly near `df.filter(cond)`

Comment: @Anji - please try again, I've corrected one logic issue. If the code is still "not working", please describe in detail, what is wrong (if it's an error, what it says).